# Streaming Flash Video - getting my feet wet

Tags: video-streaming, video-hosting, h.264

I'm working on a project that will involve having a couple thousand short videos online. I haven't done anything with online video before and this is all a bit new to me, so I am looking for some general advice...

I would like to use Flowplayer, and I would like to encode the videos as H264s. I am enamoured with Flowplayer's slow motion feature, which if I understand correctly, is only available using a Wowza server.

I'm wondering: Is it advisable to use a delivery network of some sort? (Flowplayer seems to have a partnership with HDDN, and recommends them. http://www.hddn.com/) Or would I be better off purchasing Wowza and installing it on our own server? (At first glance, it looks as though signing up with a network like HDDN is much simpler, but perhaps there are problems that come along with this...?)

Any tips / warnings of imminent peril would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm in a similar position.  I'd like to use flowplayer with Red5.  I'd be interested to see what else comes up on here.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using lighttpd to stream to flowplayer and was pretty impressed by the ease of setup, reliability, speed and small footprint it used. You can't use the slow motion/fast forward features though.

Maybe you could setup a development server to compare lighttpd to wowza to see if it's really worth it?

Comment: Red5 streaming server looks interesting too

Comment: Have you tried mod_h264 ? http://h264.code-shop.com/trac